# Declaring an empty class in OWL

Tags: semantic-web, owl, protege

Does OWL allow an ontology to contain just an empty class? Do classes have to contain some individuals? Does

```
<owl:Class rdf:ID="Human"/>
```

mean that "Human" is an empty class?

If an ontology contains an empty class, could the individuals be defined in another ontology that extends it?

Similarly, could an individual be declared without being a member of any class in an ontology?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can declare an empty class.

Yes, you can declare individuals of such a class in a different ontology.

Both of these are completely normal. The idea of ontologies is that they can be shared, that is, one party defines the classes and properties, and then other parties can *use it* by actually instantiating the classes and using the properties to describe them.

Every individual is implicitly a member of the `owl:Thing` class. So the closest you can get to declaring an individual with no class is to make it a member of `owl:Thing`:

```
<owl:Thing rdf:ID="MyThing"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. However, if the class is defined to be empty in one but defined to have individuals in another, then wouldn't this be a contradiction?

Comment: No. OWL is based on the Open World Assumption (OWA). If your ontology doesn't list any instances for some class, then it is simply unknown whether the class has any instances. The absence of any instances doesn't contradict the existence of instances.

Comment: Note that the snippet you provided in your question doesn't actually declare that the class has no individuals. It simply doesn't list any individuals, that's all. If you actually want to declare that a class has no individuals, then you can make it a subclass of `owl:Nothing`. In that case, if another ontology would declare an individual of that class, it would indeed be a contradiction.

Comment: Hmm, yes it's a contradiction, no matter OWA or CWA. If a class is empty it cannot have instances. However, to reach this conclusion you would need an OWL reasoner which reasons over the merge of the ontology with the data which instanciates it. If an ontology imports another ontology, then the reasoner is bound to merge the imported with the importing ontoogy.

Comment: Richard, I think you misunderstood Kate comment. Still, you're right, the snippet doesn't define an empty class.